# Crypto API - CryptRetrieveTimeStamp

Tags: c++, cryptoapi, trusted-timestamp

Good day,

Can someone please help me using the Crypto Api function, CryptRetrieveTimeStamp?
I successfully use CryptSignMessage to sign my message and now I want to timestamp the data at a TSA, but CryptRetrieveTimeStamp always return *TRUST_E_TIME_STAMP* error.

My function looks as follows, *pbMessage* and *cbMessage* are the data and size received from CryptSignMessage:

```
PCRYPT_TIMESTAMP_CONTEXT tcontext = NULL;
HCERTSTORE hStore = NULL;


fReturn = CryptRetrieveTimeStamp(widestr.c_str(),
       TIMESTAMP_NO_AUTH_RETRIEVAL, 
       0, 
       szOID_RSA_MD5, 
       NULL, 
       (const BYTE*)pbMessage, 
       cbMessage, 
       &tcontext, 
       NULL, 
       &hStore);
```

I know the error means: *The time stamp signer and or certificate could not be verified or is malformed*. But I have no idea what or how to solve this error?

Any help/hints would be appreciated.
Thanks,
Magda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Viewing the request/response through wireshark gave better insight into the problem.

The TSA is a valid TSA, but the encoding was wrong. Changing *szOID_RSA_MD5* to *szOID_NIST_sha256* solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd433803%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) -

> The `CryptRetrieveTimeStamp` function encodes a time stamp request and
>   retrieves the time stamp token from a location specified by a URL to a
>   Time Stamping Authority (TSA).

Most likely you didn't provide the valid TSA in first parameter, which is -

> `wszUrl` [in]
>
> A pointer to a null-terminated wide character string that contains the URL of the TSA to which to send the request.

**Edit** - The suggested solution is to change time stamping authority.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the timestamp retrieval is that it is not compatible with OpenSSL... Not related to your question though.